# How to backup OneNote files that are in OneDrive

Tags: backup, onedrive, onenote

I have OneNote files in OneDrive. I want to back them up locally. How do I do that?

I've tried File -> options -> save & backup and clicked on "Back up All Notebooks Now", then I went to the Backup folder... only Quick Notes was backed up... no notebooks that are synced to OneDrive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the "Also backup notebooks stored on Sharepoint"? This option is actually for all notebooks that have an URL as storage location, so notebooks on OneNote as well.

Also to be backed up the notebooks have to be currently opened in OneNote